# How to get Spring Actuator build information locally?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

When accessing my Spring Actuator `/info` endpoint I receive the following information:

```
{
    "git": {
        "branch": "8743b52063cd84097a65d1633f5c74f5",
        "commit": {
            "id": "b3j2924",
            "time": "05.07.2021 @ 10:00:00 UTC"
        }
    },
    "build": {
        "encoding": {
            "source": "UTF-8"
        },
        "version": "1.0",
        "artifact": "my-artifact",
        "name": "my-app",
        "time": 0451570333.122000000,
        "group": "my.group"
    }
}
```

My project does not maintain a `META-INF/build-info.properties` file.

I now wanted to write a unit-test for that exact output but get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual:
  "{"git":{"branch":"8743b52063cd84097a65d1633f5c74f5","commit":{"id":"b3j2924","time":"05.07.2021 @ 10:00:00 UTC"}}}"
to contain:
  "build"
```

The whole `build` block is missing in the output.

My questions are the following:

1. What needs to be done to access the build information during a local unit-test run without providing a `META-INF/build-info.properties`.
2. From where does Spring Actuator retrieve the actual build information when my project does not has a `META-INF/build-info.properties` file so it gives me the output from above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build-info.properties file is typically generated at build time by Spring Boot's [Maven](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-info) or [Gradle](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.3/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#integrating-with-actuator.build-info) plugins.